# Checkbox toggle ignores first click, toggle works fine after second click

Tags: javascript

This seems like it should be straight forward. I have an element that I want to hide when a checkbox is checked.

**Code**

```js
$(function() {
  $('#id_no_gates').click(function() {
    $("#id_gate_arm_operation").toggle(this.checked);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="no_gates" id="id_no_gates">
<table id="id_gate_arm_operation">...</table>
```

I expect that when I click the checkbox, the table should go away. But what happens is I click the checkbox once, nothing happens. Then I click the checkbox again (uncheck), and it goes away. This is the opposite of what I want. What am I missing? Does the function not get called the first time? Is '.click' the wrong trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hide the table on checked property of the checkbox then you should change your code to this

```
$("#id_gate_arm_operation").toggle(!this.checked);
```

The `.toggle` method will show the element on `true` value and hide on `false`.
So in checkbox click event when we get the updated value of the checkbox.
Hence on checked true property we need to hide the table so we will have to pass false to `.toggle` method as in the unchecked state if we click ,we will get `this.checked` as `true` and `false` in the checked state.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood how `toggle(this.checked)` worked. I thought it would toggle when changing from any value to the opposite value, rather than, as you explain, toggle based on the actual T/F value. Thank you very much!

Comment: We nee to hide on checked state and show on unchecked state but in your case its working opposite of it.